# Do you think the edge loop is ok? especially around the ears. Will it deform well after animation?

Tags: modeling

[image]

this is the project for likeness sclupt and i dont want the rig to look weird  .

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the area around the ear is not right.

The meshflow should follow the [Sternocleidomastoid muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternocleidomastoid_muscle) and not return back to the eye corner.